# Will using IMDG on top of NoSql really boost the performance of the application?

Tags: imdb, nosql

Does using a IMDG layer (Gemfire, HazelCast) on top of the NoSql db (MongoDB) improve the performance and scaleability of the application?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe. As always, "It Depends".

On what?  Primarily the characteristics of your data and your data access patterns. A few considerations (of many!) might be:

- How much data do you have, and is it feasible and/or cost-effective to even attempt to cache a portion of it in memory?

  - Are there "hot" subsets of the data which are candidates for caching? For example, in social apps the last x hours of data drive virtually all the load.
- What cache hit % do you need to achieve in order to benefit from the cache? (This is driven by your app's sensitivity to latency)
- What is the ratio between reads/writes?
- What are the consistency and reliability requirements?
- What types of reads does your app do? Complex queries? Simple GETs? In which mix?

Caching layers can be incredibly effective when used correctly. But they aren't a silver bullet. Don't expect to just slap one over your existing store and magically get "faster" or "more scalable"...